# Floated div won't fully expand

Tags: css, html, css-float

I'm trying to design a page layout with two floated `divs` which I want to use for my content area and sidebar. 
My problem with the layout is that I tested one of those floated `divs` with a lot of text content, but it does not expand to show all of the content. The last paragraph seems to overlap with my footer

I have already added `overflow: auto` to the containing `div`but it doesnt seem to work. Any ideas?

```
<body>

<div id="header">
</div><!--ends header-->

<div id="navbar">
</div><!--ends navbar-->

<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="content">

        <div class="post">
         <p> Long content tested here</p>
        </div><!--ends post-->

    </div><!--ends content-->

    <div id="sidebar">
    </div><!--ends sidebar-->

    <div id="footer">
    </div><!--ends footer-->

</div><!--ends wrapper-->

</body>
```

CSS here:

```
html{
    height:100%;
    background:url(images/green-bamboo2.jpg);
    background-attachment:fixed;
}

body{
    height:100%;
    width:80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:0;
    background:#FFFFFF;
}

#header, #navbar, #content, #sidebar, #footer{
    display:block;
}

#header{
    height:100px;
}

#navbar{
    height:50px;
    background:#CCCCCC;
}

#wrapper{
    min-height:100%;
    background:#FFFFFF;
    position:relative;
    overflow:auto;
}

#content{
    float:left;
    width:60%;
    height:auto;
    background:#99CC00;
}

#sidebar{
    float:right;
    width:40%;
    height:200px;
    background:#09F;
}

#footer{
    clear:both;
    height:150px;
    background:#339933;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your height on the div is set to auto; which is fine, but your footer div is positioned absolute which means that it won't move when the other div starts to overlap. if you make it position: relative then it should move as your div gets bigger.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue in your css.

You're using both `clear` and `position:absolute` on  `#footer`.
As a result, it does not use the clear property.

**EDIT:** See http://jsfiddle.net/WTpAx/1/ to see what it'll look like if you remove `position:absolute` from `#footer` and `min-height:100%` from `#content`.

Comment: the clear doesn't even need to be used here. the div's are not to the left or right of the footer which is overlapping the content. he just needs to change his positioning and he will be able to see all his content.

Comment: No, using float removes its sidebar and content from the flow of the document, as a consequence, if he just uses position relative on `#footer` it'll end right beside the header.

Comment: Seems Py is right about not using clear:both on my footer. It only moves it (footer) right next to the header once its position is relative. Thanks a lot for the help guys!